# Unread message feature not working in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, sqlite

I am trying to make an "unread" function for my messenger.  When I refresh try to refresh the database it shows

> There is no column with name 'read' on table 'messages'.

This error and my **"unread"** feature is not working. I am using SQlite.

**Here's my Unread migration:-**

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::table('messages', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->boolean('read')->after('to')->default(false);
        });
    }

public function down()
    {
        Schema::table('messages', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->dropColumn('read');
        });
    }
```

**Here my Messages migration:-**

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('messages', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->integer('from')->unsigned();
            $table->integer('to')->unsigned();
            $table->text('text');       
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```

**Here's my controller:-**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\User;
use App\Friend;
use App\Message;
use App\Events\NewMessage;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;

class ContactsController extends Controller
{
    public function __construct()
    {
       $this->middleware('auth');
    }

    public function index()
    {
        return view('home');
    }

    public function get(){
        $sem = Auth::user()->id;
        $contacts = DB::table('friends')
        ->where('my_id', $sem)
        ->get();

        // get a collection of items where sender_id is the user who sent us a message
        // and messages_count is the number of unread messages we have from him
        $unreadIds = Message::select(\DB::raw('`from` as sender_id, count(`from`) as messages_count'))
            ->where('to', auth()->id())
            ->where('read', false)
            ->groupBy('from')
            ->get();

        // add an unread key to each contact with the count of unread messages
        $contacts = $contacts->map(function($contact) use ($unreadIds) {
            $contactUnread = $unreadIds->where('sender_id', $contact->friends_id)->first();
            $contact->unread = $contactUnread ? $contactUnread->messages_count : 0;
            return $contact;
        });

        return response()->json($contacts);
    }

    public function getMessagesFor($id)
    {
        $messages = Message::where('from', $id)->orWhere('to', $id)->get();
        $messages = Message::where(function($q) use ($id) {
            $q->where('from', auth()->id());
            $q->where('to', $id);
        })->orWhere(function($q) use ($id){
            $q->where('from', $id);
            $q->where('to', auth()->id());
        })
        ->get();
        return response()->json($messages);
    }

    public function send(Request $request)
    {   
        $message = Message::create([
            'from' => auth()->id(),
            'to' => $request->contact_id,
            'text' => $request->text
        ]);
        broadcast(new NewMessage($message));
        return response()->json($message);
    }
}
```

**This is where contacts Ids are coming from:-**

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('friends', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->string('created_by');
            $table->string('my_id');
            $table->string('friends_id');
            $table->string('name');     
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```

I can't seem to figure out the problem and have been stuck with this since weeks, your help would really be appreciated.

Comment: Have you ran all your migrations? `php artisan migrate`?

Comment: give me  a sec let me try again

Comment: yes, i did.... ,

Comment: What does `php artisan migrate:status` look like?

Comment: ``Yes  | 2020_05_22_082929_add_read_to_messages         | 1``

Comment: I never knew something like this existed before. I am a beginner, Thanks

Comment: Are you able to copy the error that's in your `laravel.log` file?

Comment: I'm Sorry, i am not sure how to do that

Comment: before I did ``php artisan migrate:fresh`` my notifications were being shown but as i hit the contact they had to dissappear but that part wasn't taking place

Comment: `from` is a reserved word in SQL, so you have to be careful about using it as a column name. You're using `raw` queries, which means you need to worry about escaping keywords yourself. You've done it 2 out of the 3 times you reference that column, but you forgot to do it in `groupBy('from')`.

Comment: ``public function down()
    {
        Schema::table('messages', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->dropColumn('read');
                    });
    }``

Comment: This is My Drop section of unread messages

Comment: The file located in `storage/logs/laravel.log` should have the full error trace if you are able to copy that here?

Comment: yes I fund the file, How do you want me to share it with you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few things that may be causing you issues with your migration.

- You have a couple of reserved words in SQL (thought maybe not in
  SQLite) that could be causing an issue.  I would remove them in favor
  of something that is not potentially causing a conflict.
- You might assign foreign keys to the database so it will play nice
  with your models.  Then you don't have to go through the whole
  `DB::raw('from...` stuff, it is automatically assigned by the model
  if you set up the relationships correctly.
- I think the issue you are having though, is that you may be using the
  migration a bit differently that expected.  Why not put the boolean
  field on the original migration?  If this migration isn't run, or is
  run in the wrong order, or if it is run in `down()` mode, that `read`
  field will not be in the database table.

I suggest to test, start with the following migration.  Make note of the different (non-conflicting) field names and the auto-increment field:

```
Schema::create('messages', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->integer('from_id')->unsigned();
        $table->integer('to_id')->unsigned();
        $table->boolean('has_read')->default(false);
        $table->text('text');       
        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

Run a fresh migration on the database with this.  Rework your controller code to work with the new field names and test.  If this fixes the error:

> There is no column with name 'read' on table 'messages'.

Then I would recommend adding in the foreign keys to those ids like this for example:

```
$table->foreign('from_id')->references('id')->on('users');
```

But this is a whole different issue and requires re-working of your controller db draws.  For now, see if the above migration will solve the original error.

Comment: Sure.. I'll try this method

Comment: can you please suggest me the changes to be made in the controller

Comment: Sure - lets just test this first with a simple query to see if the error has been resolved with the new migration:  try this `$unreadIds = Message::where('to_id', auth()->id())
            ->where('has_read', false)->get()`   If this does NOT error out, you have solved your issue.  You can then play around with re-working the rest of the query to suit.  IE JUST run this in the controller to test - don't run any other queries.  let's just see if we've solved the issue.

Comment: just give me  a sec on to it

Comment: doesn't shows any error and doesn't shows any output either

Comment: I tried my old way and the notification with the count of unread messages were being shown but they were not disappearing as I hit the contact

Comment: Using the above and the query I wrote in the comments, what happens if you `dd($unreadIds)`?  If you get an output without an error of a missing field on the table, this is the solution to the original problem :)

Comment: using your controller query i am unable to send or fetch my texts and when i run ``dd($unreadIds)`` it is all sort of crashing cant see my contacts

Comment: basically what i have done is taken this package and added a friends table and from that table i am fetching the data that the package need everthing is working perfectly fine except the notification  **Github Link**:- https://github.com/AfikDeri/Messenger-App-VueJS-and-Laravel

Comment: No, you would n't be able to see contacts - you don't have the FKs set up yet.  If you JUST run that query after migration, does it solve the 'missing read column' error?  Thats all we are trying to do at this point.  The attachment of the contacts is a whole different issue and requires a bit more work.  But let's solve the original issue first just see if you get the dump.  IF the **Message** model has relationships within, it will crash all over the place because we've changed the names of the columns.  But if the dump crashes WITHOUT the table column failure-we've solved the issue above

Comment: Have to head out to meetings and have to step away.  But, keep it simple.  Solve one problem at a time.  If you get the column error solved, then move on to the next bits.  Add complexity at each step.  If the column error is solved, test against the next pieces one at a time.  If you need to, ask another question on the relationships and the links between the message and the friends/users tables.

Comment: actually the error occurred when I ran this error ``php artisan migrate:refresh --path=/database/migrations/2020_05_22_082929_add_read_to_messages.php`` but if i run just ``php artisan migrate:fresh`` it ran fine. but now its all working fine. Sorry for being such a noob

Comment: No worries :)  Yes, that is expected.  Your original migration was the cause of the error from your question.  Taking out that Unread migration and adding the 'has_read' column into the base migration solves the issue.  The crash on the refresh was b/c you had a duplicate column based on the old Unread and the column already being in the table.  You can now move on to the next issue of setting up the Model to reflect the correct migration now that the fresh migration works - but that's a different set of work.

Comment: Yes, So if you are not frustrated..Can you help me with that cuz i cant figure out that problem aswell

Comment: No worries, not frustrated at all :)  I know what its like to be new.  However, rather than try to answer a different question here in comments, please close this one (mark as correct as it solves the original problem) and post a new question specific to your needs using the new, working code.  If I am not around, someone else will surely be able to help, and I will check in later too.

Comment: Sure... Thanks for all the patience and help..ik its too much to ask but would you mind providing me anything where I can contact you for guidance in future..You can always say no..But again thanks for all the help 

Comment: Glad to help :)  Just add a comment to one of these answers and I'll see it.  You can always delete later after its been seen.  Easiest way I think.