# Trying to sort and get collection of data

Tags: mysql, database, laravel, eloquent

I am trying to get the data of users form the `users` table by passing in the id's from `reports` table 
I want to display the `reason` the name of the `reported_user` and the name of the `reported_by` 
when I run `dd($report->all());` it shows this:-

```
array:2 [▼
  0 => App\Report {#1057 ▼
    #fillable: array:3 [▼
      0 => "reported_by"
      1 => "reported_user"
      2 => "reason"
    ]
    #connection: "sqlite"
    #table: "reports"
    #primaryKey: "id"
    #keyType: "int"
    +incrementing: true
    #with: []
    #withCount: []
    #perPage: 15
    +exists: true
    +wasRecentlyCreated: false
    #attributes: array:6 [▶]
    #original: array:6 [▶]
    #changes: []
    #casts: []
    #classCastCache: []
    #dates: []
    #dateFormat: null
    #appends: []
    #dispatchesEvents: []
    #observables: []
    #relations: []
    #touches: []
    +timestamps: true
    #hidden: []
    #visible: []
    #guarded: array:1 [▶]
  }
  1 => App\Report {#1056 ▶}
]
```

I am facing this error aswell:-
 **Property [reported_user] does not exist on this collection instance.** 
and the same goes for `$reportedBy`

**Here's my controller**

```
public function reports()
    {
        $report = Report::all();

        $reportedUser = DB::table('users')
        ->where('id', '=', $report->reported_user)
        ->get();

        $reportedBy = DB::table('users')
        ->where('id', '=', $report->reported_by)
        ->get();



        return view('admin.report', compact('report'));
}
```

**Here's my reports table:-**

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('reports', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->integer('reported_by')->unsigned();
            $table->integer('reported_user')->unsigned();
            $table->string('reason');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```

Can anyone tell me if this is the right way to execute this task and why am I getting such error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to draw a property from a collection instead of a single instance of an object.

The collection `$report` is not a single object, it is a collection of reports.  Each report *within* that collection will have the property `reported_user`, but not the collection as a whole.

To fix, you can either grab a single report from the DB:

```
 $report = Report::first();
```

where you will have access to the `reported_user` field for this object, or you can loop on the reports you have drawn from the original *collection*:

```
foreach($report as $r){
  $reportedUser = DB::table('users')
    ->where('id', '=', $r->reported_user)
    ->first();
 }
```

Suggest naming the original report collection as `$reports` to prevent confusion and show that it is a collection, not a single report object.

Also - note I did the same thing in the loop - grab an object, not a collection using the `first()` method, instead of `get()`.

**EDIT**:

The above was a simple example to explain.  To prevent many DB calls, you can also do this:

```
$reports = Report::pluck('reported_user');

$reportedUsers = DB::table('users')
   ->whereIn('id', $reports)
   ->get();
```

You now have a collection of all the `reported_user` with full detail.  You can then loop on that `$reportedUsers` collection and get the detail behind each one.

Comment: wouldn't this will just give me one user? because I want to display the detail list of all the reported_user and reported_by

Comment: Yes, one user *per loop*.  The issue is that you originally draw a collection with `$report = Report::all();` and are trying to get a reported user from that whole collection.  If you use the loop above with that collection and add each `$reportedUser` to an array or collection of users, you will have your list of all reported users.  You are close - it will work - you just need to work through the loop instead of a single object within the `$reportedUser` grab.  Of course, you can tighten this code to get all the IDs - let me edit the answer and show you this too.  One min

Comment: yes, it all make sense. But usually when I run dd in a collection what I get is the values but in this situation ``dd($report->all());`` I don't see any values why is that?

Comment: Would You mind helping me out with another question, if yes then here's the link:-  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62397745/unread-message-feature-not-working-in-laravel?noredirect=1#comment110357597_62397745

Comment: Ah!  Because we're just pulling the single field `reported_user`.  If you changed `pluck()` for `get()` you would see all the values in the `dd()`.  But, pluck is handy for times like this when we don't need the expensive database call for the WHOLE object - we just need the IDs. :)

Comment: Glad to help.  I'll look at the other question as well... no idea if I'll know anything about it, but i'll give it a read!